# Terraform aws_eip resource getting "Error" of Value for unconfigurable attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, hashicorp

I am new to Terraform and following a tutorial on how to create aws_elasticip module. When i perform 'terraform plan' this issue is present and i can't move forward with creating my terraform file.

```
 terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
}

resource "aws_eip" "lb" {
  domain = "vpc"
}
```

I have also attempted to do this with a instance variable declared and the error still persists

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc_a" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_instance" "server_a" {
    ami = "ami-06464c878dbe46da4"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
}

resource "aws_eip" "lb" {
    instance = aws_instance.server_a.id
    domain = "vpc"
}
```

The error I am getting is below.

```
│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│ 
│   with aws_eip.lb,
│   on main.tf line 25, in resource "aws_eip" "lb":
│   25:     domain = "vpc"
│ 
│ Can't configure a value for "domain": its value will be decided
│ automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The semantic versioning specification you provided in the config for the provider block is `~> 4.16` which resolves to `>= 4.16 < 5.0.0`. The `domain` parameter was migrated from a `Computed` attribute to an input attribute in the `aws_eip` resource in [version 5.0.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/31567) as a pseudo-replacement for the `vpc` parameter. You would need to upgrade the AWS provider to a minimum of 5.0.0 to use this parameter.